# Angular.js Strange Behavior - Button must be clicked twice for drop down menu

Tags: angularjs

In angular.js, I have a button that gives a drop down menu. The issue I am having is, consistently, I have to click on the button twice for drop down menu to appear. The first time I click on the button, I see it light up...so a click registers. But, I have to click on it a second time for the drop down menu to show. What is causing this?

directive:

```
angular.module('main.vips')
.directive('actionButton', ['ActionButtonService', function(ActionButtonService) {
    openAddVipModal = function() {
        return $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'vips/addvip.html',
            controller: 'AddVipCtrl',
            size: 'lg',
            windowClass: 'modal-fullscreen vip-modal'
        });
    }

  return {
    templateUrl: 'vips/directives/actionButton.html',
    restrict: "AE",
    replace: true,
    transclude: false,
    scope: {
      'label': "@?",
      'icon': "@?",
      'type': "@?",
      'actions': "=?"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.actions = ActionButtonService[attrs.type];
    }
  }
}]);
```

---

Service:

```
angular.module('main.vips')
.factory('ActionButtonService', function() {
  var actions = {};
  actions.loadbalancer = [
    {
      label: "Create New VIP",
      fn: function() {
        return openAddVipModal();
      },
      icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-plus"
    }, {
      label: "Add Existing VIP",
      icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-search"
    }, {
      divider: true
    }, {
      label: "Activate Selected",
      icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-play"
    }, {
      label: "Suspend Selected",
      icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-pause"
    }, {
      divider: true
    }
  ];
  actions.vip = [
    {
      label: "Create New Node",
      icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-plus"
    }, {
      label: "Add Existing Node",
      icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-search"
    }
  ];
  actions.node = [
    {
      label: "Edit Node",
      icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-plus"
    }, {
      label: "Node Stuff",
      icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-search"
    }, {
      divider: true
    } 
  ];

  return actions;

});
```

---

Template:

```
<div class="btn-group action-button-icon" dropdown>
  <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle"
          ng-class="{'btn-primary page-button': type == 'page',
          'btn-primary btn-xs': type == 'vip',
          'btn-info btn-xs': type == 'node'}"
          id="vip-actions"
          data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="{{ icon }}"></span> {{ label }}
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="vip-actions">
    <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="action in actions" ng-class="{'divider' : action.hasOwnProperty('divider')}">
      <a ng-if="action.hasOwnProperty('label')" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" 
         >
        <span class="{{ action.icon }}"></span>
        {{ action.label }}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

html:

```
  <div action-button type="loadbalancer" label="Actions" icon="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" actions="actions.loadbalancer" class="pull-right"></div>
```

Comment: If you could build a jsFiddle, Plunker, or CodePen.io example which demonstrated the problem there is a good chance people would come help you debug it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using Angular-UI and have included the Bootstrap JS file in your project? We had this exact same thing happen and found that if you include the Bootstrap JS file in your project it somehow introduces this. We solved it by removing the Bootstrap JS file from the project and let Angular-UI handle things.